# Convert Keras VGG16 preprocessing in OpenCV C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, opencv, keras

```
settings:
Tensorflow = 2.4.1, Keras = 2.4.3, Python = 3.7.9, OpenCV = 4.5.1
```

I do a transfer learning with the Keras base model of VGG16.
My own model architecture starts with:

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3), name="input_layer")

x = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input(inputs)

x = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(weights=weights, include_top=include_top, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3))(x)
```

and so on

Afterwards I freeze my model and use freeze_optimize_inference.py.
Hence my frozen layers look like:

```
x

VGG16/tf.__operators__.getitem/strided_slice/stack

VGG16/tf.__operators__.getitem/strided_slice/stack_1

VGG16/tf.__operators__.getitem/strided_slice/stack_2

VGG16/tf.__operators__.getitem/strided_slice

VGG16/tf.nn.bias_add/BiasAdd/bias

VGG16/tf.nn.bias_add/BiasAdd

VGG16/vgg16/block1_conv1/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp/resource

VGG16/vgg16/block1_conv1/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp
```

and so on

In C++ I use OpenCV and read my model with:

```
tensorflowNet = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow("freeze_model_inference.pb");
```

This gives me the error:

```
OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64- 
vc14\opencv\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp:1527: error: (-213:The 
function/feature is not implemented) StridedSlice with stride -1 in function 
'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20201117::`anonymous-namespace'::TFImporter::populateNet'

empty model
```

For me it says that the problem comes from the vgg16.preprocess_input-layers. I can create a model without theses layers but then I have the problem "How can I exactly implement the VGG16 preprocessing in C++?"

Answer (score 0):

According to [`tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/vgg16/preprocess_input?hl=pt) VGG preprocessing simply involves converting from RGB to BGR and subtracting ImageNet mean values which are `[123.68, 116.779, 103.939]` without any scaling.

You can achieve this by simply using the `cv::dnn::blobFromImage` function:

```
const double     SCALE_FACTOR = 1.0; # No scaling
const cv::Size   INPUT_SIZE   = cv::Size( 224, 224 ); # Adjust accordingly
const cv::Scalar RGB_MEAN     = cv::Scalar( 123.68, 116.779, 103.939 ); # RGB order
const bool       SWAP_RB      = false; # OpenCV images are already handled in BGR

cv::Mat blob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage( image, SCALE_FACTOR, INPUT_SIZE, RGB_MEAN, SWAP_RB );
```